# embedding a phaser 3 game into an existing mithril website

Tags: phaser-framework, mithril.js

I have been trying to get phaser 3 to work in an existing mithril website. All of the existing phaser 3 examples seem to work 'by magic'. There is no javascript code that mounts the phaser game into your DOM. Searching gets me nowhere. Even the ['modern' tutorial](https://snowbillr.github.io/blog/2018-04-09-a-modern-web-development-setup-for-phaser-3/) seems to just load the js and boom there's a game.

How do I incorporate a phaser game into an existing mithril framework? I can mount a pixi canvas as simply as this:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

app = new PIXI.Application 800, 600,
  backgroundColor: 0x1099bb

basicText = new PIXI.Text('Basic text in pixi')
basicText.x = 30
basicText.y = 90

app.stage.addChild basicText

export class BPScreen
  view: ->
    m '#balloon-pop',
      oncreate: ({ dom })->
        dom.appendChild app.view
```

Can I accomplish this with Phaser 3?

Comment: Note this is in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config for the phaser game there is a property called `parent` where you can pass the id of a parent element, such as a div.

So an example config is:

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    ...
    [other config options]
};
```

then in the HTML you would have something like

```
<div id="gameDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I went with the CE version and this works great. The docs are a bit sketchy for V3.

Comment: The above should also work for V3. Phaser 3 docs are here: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/index.html

Comment: I know but I didn’t realize sounds wouldn’t work in V3 yet. Kind of an important feature.